# Security hurdles to enabling sources in repo

Tags: repository

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I have the following output:

```
Hit http://mirror.transact.net.au stable Release.gpg
Ign http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable/contrib Translation-en_AU
Ign http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Hit http://mirror.transact.net.au stable Release             
Hit http://mirror.transact.net.au stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.transact.net.au stable/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://mirror.transact.net.au stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Get:1 http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/main Translation-en
Ign http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/main Translation-en_AU
Ign http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/non-free Translation-en_AU
Get:2 http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze Release [22.0 kB]
Ign http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze Release
Get:3 http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze/main amd64 Packages [72.8 kB]
Get:4 http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze/non-free amd64 Packages [3,902 B]
Fetched 98.9 kB in 3s (32.6 kB/s)   
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 07DC563D1F41B907
```

I've scoured the web but can only find esoteric solutions I cannot understand.

Is there a way to bypass the security feature blocking it without engaging in esoteric commandline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can find on the [Debian Multimedia](http://www.debian-multimedia.org/) home page

> The first package to install is `debian-multimedia-keyring`.
>
> Since Squeeze you can install this package with `apt-get` but you need to press `Y` when the package ask what to do and do not press return.

So, summing up, don't care about `apt-get update` warning, install the named package and answer `Y` when asked.

Comment: I installed debian-multimedia-keyring.  I don't know if this was expected but apt-get update succeeded after I did this.  Problem is when I try to install acroread in Synaptic, dozens of dependencies are not automatically resolved and it refuses to proceed: `acroread:
 Depends: acroread-l10n-en but it is not going to be installed or
 acroread-l10n
 Depends: acroread-debian-files but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: acroread-data but it is not going to be installed
 Depends: ia32-libs-xulrunner but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: That `apt-get` succeed is expected. For `acroread` post another question, with all relevant details.