# Unmet acroread dependencies preventing Synaptic install

Tags: debian, dependencies, synaptic

In Synaptic I am getting the error:

```
acroread: 
  Depends: acroread-l10n-en but it is not going to be installed or acroread-l10n 
  Depends: acroread-debian-files but it is not going to be installed 
  Depends: acroread-data but it is not going to be installed 
  Depends: ia32-libs-xulrunner but it is not going to be installed
```

This is unusual for me as Synaptic normally resolves dependencies automatically; moreover acroread is a very popular package.

I want to know how to get around this.

I'm on Deb 6 64 bit.

acroread is being sourced from `deb http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze main non-free`.

For possibly relevant details also see [Security hurdles to enabling sources in repo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20000/security-hurdles-to-enabling-sources-in-repo/20003#20003).

Edit (@enzotib):

```
# Debian packages for stable
deb http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
# Uncomment the deb-src line if you want 'apt-get source'
# to work with most packages.
# deb-src http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

# Security updates for stable
# deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze main non-free
#contains Adobe Reader
```

@Gilles

```
peter@peter-deb:~$ apt-cache policy acroread acroread-debian-files ia32-libs-xulrunner
acroread-debian-files:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.4.2
  Version table:
     9.4.2 0
        500 http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
acroread:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 9.4.2-0.0
  Version table:
     9.4.2-0.0 0
        500 http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/non-free amd64 Packages
ia32-libs-xulrunner:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.8.1.3-0.5
  Version table:
     1.8.1.3-0.5 0
        500 http://www.debian-multimedia.org/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

@Gilles:

```
peter@peter-deb:~$ sudo aptitude install acroread
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  acroread acroread-data{a} acroread-debian-files{a} 
  acroread-dictionary-en{a} acroread-l10n-en{a} ia32-libs{a} 
  ia32-libs-gtk{a} ia32-libs-xulrunner{a} lib32asound2{ab} lib32bz2-1.0{a} 
  lib32gcc1{a} lib32ncurses5{a} lib32stdc++6{a} lib32v4l-0{a} lib32z1{a} 
  libc6-i386{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 16 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,955 kB/102 MB of archives. After unpacking 254 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  lib32asound2: Depends: libasound2 (= 1.0.23-2.1) but 1.0.24.1-2 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     acroread [Not Installed]                           
2)     acroread-data [Not Installed]                      
3)     acroread-debian-files [Not Installed]              
4)     acroread-dictionary-en [Not Installed]             
5)     acroread-l10n-en [Not Installed]                   
6)     ia32-libs [Not Installed]                          
7)     ia32-libs-gtk [Not Installed]                      
8)     ia32-libs-xulrunner [Not Installed]                
9)     lib32asound2 [Not Installed]                       



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

More error info:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and of all files matching `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`?

Comment: @enzotib  Ok, I have posted the contents of my sources.list file, but what am I supposed to retrieve for `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`?  Any why is the wildcard (*) included?

Comment: enzotib meant to post every file called something`.list` in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Debian-multimedia no longer provides acroread, does it? What does `apt-cache policy acroread acroread-debian-files ia32-libs-xulrunner` say?

Comment: @Gilles: See OP for output.  What command do I need to issue for to get a list for `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`?

Comment: The command would be `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`, but I don't think this information is needed (`apt-cache policy` already gives the relevant parts of that). Hmmm, you should be able to install. If you have a file `/etc/apt/preferences`, post it. And try `aptitude install acroread`, it may be cleverer or have a better error message.

Comment: Neither of those files exist for me.

Comment: You should check why `libasound2` version 1.0.24.1-2 is installed (this is from unstable), and probably remove it. This should not normally be installed unless multimedia is installing it for you. What does `apt-cache policy libasound2` show?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha It shows `libasound2:
  Installed: 1.0.24.1-2
  Candidate: 1.0.24.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.24.1-2 0
        500 http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`.  What does that mean?

Comment: @ptrcao: It means you have a version of libasound2 from testing, (i.e. more recent than squeeze) from mirror.transact.net.au. Testing is not listed in your sources, so I am unclear how that happened. Try removing it (`apt-get purge libasound2`) and see what happens. And make sure you don't have any testing sources listed. The fact that policy is recognising the source means it is listed somewhere in the sources, if I not mistaken. If you do, you need to set up `/etc/apt/preferences`, so they don't get automatically installed. BTW, you do want security updates, so uncomment that.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of problem above. Quoting from the post:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  lib32asound2: Depends: libasound2 (= 1.0.23-2.1) but 1.0.24.1-2 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
```

This means that `lib32asound2` has `libasound2` as a dependency. However, 
the version of `libasound2` installed (1.0.24.1-2) is of higher version number than that required by `lib32asound2` (1.0.23-2.1). This is causing errors for the package manager (aptitude), since without special prompting it will not downgrade the package to a lower version.

As posted, the version information is

```
libasound2: 
  Installed: 1.0.24.1-2 
  Candidate: 1.0.24.1-2 
  Version table: 
  *** 1.0.24.1-2 0 500 http://mirror.transact.net.au/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages 
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

This seems to be missing the stable version. I have

```
$ apt-cache policy libasound2
libasound2:
  Installed: 1.0.23-2.1
  Candidate: 1.0.23-2.1
  Version table:
     1.0.24.1-3 0
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.0.23-2.1 0
        500 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The immediate solution is to remove `libasound2` with `apt-get purge libasound2` and make sure there are no testing sources listed. The post did not list any, but `apt-cache` would not show information about sources that were not listed, assuming the cache is up to date. So also run `apt-get update` to make sure the cache is up to date. Also, enable security updates for stable.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20000/security-hurdles-to-enabling-sources-in-repo), it looks like you've just installed the Debian Multimedia repository keyring. Installing the package automatically registers the signing key with `apt-key`, but the signature is verified when you download the package list (i.e. during an update operation). As long as you haven't done that, the packages from the Debian Multimedia repository are untrusted and therefore (if I remember correctly) not installable through Synaptic by default.

If this is indeed the problem, just run `apt-get update` (or the update command in Aptitude or Synaptic) once after installing the `debian-multimedia-keyring` package.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem persists after doing so...  Also see output for aptitude in OP above.

Comment: this information about my system could be relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19898/command-to-install-linux-headers-fails.  It is from yet another problem I was having earlier that concerns my sources.list.

Answer (score 0):

Reply for some visitors coming from google to this 4 years old topic:

just manually install ia32-libs-xurlrunner from deb package found somewhere on the internet helped me, for some reason I could not find this package in official or deb-multimedia repisitories

for debian squeeze I found it here:
http://fami-net.dlinkddns.com/mirrors/debian/squeeze/deb-multimedia.org/squeeze/pool/main/i/ia32-libs-xulrunner/